# Xamarin - Cant start SDK or AVD

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, sdk, visual-studio-2017

So I have just installed the community version of Visual Studio 2017 and added Xamarin to it. When the installation was over, a error log was created saying in it that the SDK and Emulator components were not downloaded properly. So I redownloaded and same thing. I then tried modifying and repairing, again nothing helped - still the same problem.

Now when I start VS without minding the errors, I am not able to access the SDK and AVD. I click on the icons and nothing happens. I checked the path to the SDK (looks alright to me, but I guess as the error log said - SDK might not be properly installed).

I am in a corporate environment and am not allowed to download just the SDK from the android website.

I am basically trying to reach out to you all for help. All tips and answers are appreciated.

Cheers!

**Error Log:**

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)

Incomplete components
    Android NDK (R13B) (Component.Android.NDK.R13B,version=13.1.6)
    Android SDK setup (API level 23) (Component.Android.SDK23,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) (Component.HAXM,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

    Package 'AndroidSDKV2,version=24.4.1.9' failed to download from 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=824150'.
        Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidSDKV2;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80131509
        Impacted workloads
            Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Impacted components
            Android SDK setup (API level 23) (Component.Android.SDK23,version=15.0.26208.0)
            Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2,version=15.0.26208.0)
            Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) (Component.HAXM,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Details
            WebClient download failed: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
            Bits download failed: Error context: BG_ERROR_CONTEXT_REMOTE_FILE, Error code: -2145844841
            WinInet download failed: Url 'http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe' returned HTTP status code: 403

    Package 'AndroidNDK_R13B,version=13.1.5,chip=x64' failed to download from 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=833504'.
        Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidNDK_R13B;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80131509
        Impacted workloads
            Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Impacted components
            Android NDK (R13B) (Component.Android.NDK.R13B,version=13.1.6)
        Details
            WebClient download failed: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
            Bits download failed: Error context: BG_ERROR_CONTEXT_REMOTE_FILE, Error code: -2145844841
            WinInet download failed: Url 'http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64.zip' returned HTTP status code: 403
```

Comment: Can you please post all logs/diagnostics information you have?

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54521

Comment: Jon That doesn't give a solution, rather states the same problem.

Comment: @AbbasZoeb in you log there is a list of incomplete components and urls to them down the log. Download these manually and try again

Comment: That's right, i guess i cant download it because i am in a corporate environment and doesn't allow me to access to any download site. Any tips on how to over come this? I actually talked to the security at my company and they declined my request to download the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using windows 10, check if Hyper-V and Hyper-V Tools are installed. 
Open the RUN Command on your start menu, or using Windows + R - Type "appwiz.cpl" - click on "Turn Windows features on or off" and check if Hyper-V are selected and installed.

If not, select-it and restart your machine, and this mus solve your xamarin issue.

If, this dont solve, this could be a firewall issue, and this maybe blocking the download of xamarin tools.